# Read barcode using zbar sdk in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, barcode, zbar-sdk

I want to read barcode from camera using zbar sdk in windows phone.
There is SDK available for iPhone and Android platforms, chack this link
http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/

I am not sure any sdk available for zbar barcode in windows phone.

**Edit:** Currently, I am using zXing barcode library to scan barcode, but it does not support some barcode formats which are supported by zbar library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a another option on WP7 for barcode scanning - `ZXing` library. Look to [ZXing Helper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2011/11/07/wp7-real-time-video-scan-a-barcode-qr-code-in-your-app-using-zxing-lib.aspx), maybe it will be suitable for you